# Angular4 provided service is undefined in public function

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have 2 services. The first service is map function in http CRUD Function. The second service is just a service to do something that was provided in the first service.

When I inject the second service to first service, Inject looks like a success  and constructor second service defined.

I called the function in my first service function in http CRUD map function, Problem is map function in the second service object is null.

my source below down.

**A Service Class**

```
@injectable()
export class AService {
    constructor(private bs: BService){
        console.log(this.bs); // that bs variable was defined
    }

    public parser(response: Response){
        this.bs.dosometing(); // that bs variable was undefined
        /* this function is http CRUD map function */
    }
}
```

**B Service Class**

```
@injectable()
export class BService {
    constructor(){

    }

    public dosomting(){
         // do something
    }
}
```

**Http Service Class**

```
@injectable()
export class MyHttpServiceClass {
    constructor(private as: AService,private http){

    }

    public httpRequest(): observable<any>{
         return http.get(url)
             .map(this.as.parser)
             .catch(errorchecker);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what was problem is.

Could you please help me?

Comment: the decorator of a service has to be '@Injectable()' right? you have '@injectable'. is it a typing mistake when you copy to stackoverflow?

Comment: you've made spelling mistakes while defining `class`

Comment: sorry @Injectable is mistyping @Injectable() is correct

Answer (score 0):

Spelling mistake while defining class...

**@injectable** must be **@Injectable()**